# get data from thumb oximeter through microphone jack using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, getusermedia

I have an old oximeter(the kind that attaches to your thumb).  I wanted to see if I could plug it in to the microphone jack on my PC and stream the data to an iFrame using the getUserMedia API.

here is the JS I have so far:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext ||
                  window.webkitAudioContext;

const context = new AudioContext();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).
then((stream) => {
    const microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const filter = context.createBiquadFilter();

    microphone.connect(filter);

    var frame = createEle("iframe");//createEle is just create element function from my library

    frame.sandbox = "allow-scripts";
    updateFrame();

    function updateFrame(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            frame.srcdoc = filter.context.listener.value;//i want frame to display oximeter value and refresh every second
            console.log(filter.context.listener);
            updateFrame();
        },1000);
    }
    heartPage.append(frame);//heartPage is just a static element on my page
});
```

Comment: Does the oximeter definitely send analog data that the computer reads as audio? Is it designed for plugging into computers, or does the audio connector normally go into another device?

Comment: the oximeter plugs in and my computer recognizes that it's there.  When i look at the input on the realTek audio settings page, the "test your microphone" meter goes up and down.  Perhaps something is wrong with my settings?

Comment: I think i need a better understanding of the DOM build to use this feature.  Either that, or my oximeter is faulty.  Other than what's on Mozilla and Microsoft docs, are their any good tutorials i should be aware of?